# Can a bad coolant temperature sensor or a bad wheel bearing hub cause my check transmission light to come on?

Tags: ford, transmission, cooling-system, sensor, explorer

I have an 05 Ford Explorer Eddie Bauer.  The check transmission light will come on and the o/d light will flash after driving it for a while. I know my rear hub needs to be replaced, but recently was told my coolant temperature sensor needs to be replaced too. I have taken it to a garage that specializes in transmission problems but was advised no codes came up for it. So, is the problem because of the sensor, hub, or both? And is it possible that the sensor isn't bad but possibly the wiring?

Comment: Also, the transmission & overdrive lights go off after I shut the vehicle off.

Comment: Welcome to the site. I cannot tell you specifically about your issue, but would suggest the three things are completely unrelated. I suggest you get the coolant temp sensor replaced as soon as possible as this causes poor gas mileage and if bad enough other more expensive things can arise from it. Fix one issue at a time and see if things change.